# Database connection failed. It is possible that the database is overloaded or otherwise not running properly

Tags: moodle

The error below is displayed when 10 users are concurrently taking quiz in Moodle .Database Name:Postgres SQL

> Error: Database connection failed.
> It is possible that the database is overloaded or otherwise not running properly.
> The site administrator should also check that the database details have been correctly specified in config.php

I checked my config.php where everything is OK, but I'm getting this error when the users are taking the quiz.

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced this issue, So i decided to post my solution here.

Please revert all the changes which you have done in any config file.
In my case I had changed `php.ini` file, reverting the changes solved my issue.
Hope this will be helpful in future.

Answer (score 0):

I did a de- and reinstallation of the browser you are using. In my case it was Firefox.